# Finding a username in list of class objects

Tags: arrays, list, class, authentication

I'm working on this Bank database system, now I'm running into problems. I don't understand why it thinks that the list doesn't have the attribute `username`.

Here is the error code

```
'list' object has no attribute 'username'
```

My code:

```
list = []

class Bank():
#did everything here
class User(Bank):
#did everything here

#already gathered all the variables
list.append(User(company, code, name, balance, username, password))

while True:
    login = input("Username: ")
    if login in list.username:
      index = list.username.index(login)
      break
    else:
      print("There is no such username!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is telling you that the `list` object does not have an attribute called `username`. When you are adding users to the list, you are not changing the attributes associated with the `list` object, you are simply adding elements to the list. To see a list of some of the attributes for the `list` object, you can use the command `dir(list)`. You'll see that `append` is one of the listed methods for the class, and you have used this to append items to your list.

There are two potential solutions to your problem that I can think of. One is using a dictionary instead of a list. Here you would create use the usernames as keys and the actual users as values. This would look something like

```
users = dict()

class Bank():
#did everything here
class User(Bank):
#did everything here

#already gathered all the variables
users[username] = User(company, code, name, balance, username, password)

while True:
    login = input("Username: ")
    if username in users:
      # do whatever you would like to do
      break
    else:
      print("There is no such username!")
```

If you really would like to have an index then you can also create a list of users and then retrieve the index of the user via its username in the list

```
users = []
usernames = []
users.append(User(company, code, name, balance, username, password))
usernames.append(username)
while True:
    login = input("Username: ")
    if username in usernames:
      index = usernames.index(username)
      break
    else:
      print("There is no such username!")
```

Again though, this could also be solved by just keeping a list of users and a dictionary that maps from username to the index of that user in the list

```
users = []
usernames = dict()
users.append(User(company, code, name, balance, username, password))
usernames[username] = len(users) - 1
while True:
    login = input("Username: ")
    if username in usernames:
      index = usernames[username]
      break
    else:
      print("There is no such username!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at all the attributes a certain method has by running:

```
print('\n'.join(dir(the_method)))
```

In your case, it's:

```
print('\n'.join(dir(list)))
```

Output:

```
__add__
__class__
__contains__
__delattr__
__delitem__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__getitem__
__gt__
__hash__
__iadd__
__imul__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__iter__
__le__
__len__
__lt__
__mul__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__reversed__
__rmul__
__setattr__
__setitem__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
append
clear
copy
count
extend
index
insert
pop
remove
reverse
sort
```

As you can see, there is indeed no attribute `username`. What you are trying to do is to iterate through the list,
retrieving the `username` of each class object.

**Here is the corrected version:**

```
list = []

class Bank():
#did everything here
class User(Bank):
#did everything here

#already gathered all the variables
list.append(User(company, code, name, balance, username, password))

while True:
    login = input("Username: ")
    for i, user in enumerate(list):
        if user.username == login:
            index = i
            break
    else:
      print("There is no such username!")
```